# Add a new user to existing group chat in Quickblox

Tags: quickblox

How can I add a new user to existing group chat ? 
Lets say that I have a group chat with A, B and C . 
I need to add a user D to this chat .

I am using Android and JS SDKs .

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, on groupchat manager you will need to call method updateDialog(QBDialog dialog, QBRequestUpdateBuilder requestBuilder), with the help of which a new array of users' IDs will be transferred. And you will also need to inform newly added chat users that they were added, as no push notification will be sent automatically.